# Where is .xsd located for http://www.w3.org/2007/app?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd, google-api

If I'm defining a schema (using Visual Studio 2010's XML Editor) for a business object, how can I import external namespaces? I'm extending the schema for Google Commerce Search, but how do I define the namespace-prefixed elements? e.g. when querying some of my product data, one element ,`edited`, belonging to the `app` namespace looks like:

```
<app:edited>2012-01-17T17:22:05.182Z</app:edited>
```

Visual Studio suggests I might need to import the .xsd file for the `http://www.w3.org/2007/app` namespace. Do I need to find other .xsd files for the rest of the namespaces already included in the Google product feeds? e.g. `xmlns:sc` and `xmlns:scp` Where do I find these? Or am I going about this completely wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="entry"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"
    xmlns:sc="http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009"
    xmlns:scp="http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009/products">

  <xs:element name="entry">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:anyURI"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="published" type="xs:date"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="updated" type="xs:date"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <!-- how do I define the <app:edited type="date" /> element here?? -->
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get hold of the schemas. Then you can add them into visual studio's schema store:

[image]

This means that any XML instance documents you author in visual studio have access to the schema store from a validation perspective.

Then you modify your schema. First import the new schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema ... xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" ... >
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" />
  ...
```

Then make a reference to the type you want to use from that schema

```
<xs:element name="entry">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      ...
      <!-- how do I define the <app:edited type="date" /> element here?? -->
      <xs:element ref="app:edited" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Circling back to my original question--where is the .xsd file for http://www.w3.org/2007/app? Do I have to make it myself? Is it hosted at w3.org?

Comment: It looks like the Atom Publishing Protocol has a RelaxNG Compact Schema and no XSD schema. So you are out of luck in this case. You could convert the RelaxNG schema to an XSD with a tool like Trang: http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html

Comment: Where is the RelaxNG Compact Schema for `http://www.w3.org/2007/app`? Where are you finding this information?

Comment: RelaxNG Compact schema is an appendix in this document: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5023

Comment: I apologize if I'm not phrasing the question right or *completely* misinterpreting, but where is either 1) the RelaxNG schema **file** I would attempt to convert or 2) the `http://www.w3.org/2007/app` schema **file** I would attempt to import? It sounds like question 1) would create the file for question 2). Am I missing something?

Comment: David I don't know where the file is. However you can create your own RNG schema file from the link above. The schema is in appendix B.  As for the XSD schema I don't know if this even exists. I think they just created a RNG schema for AtomPub protocol. You could create the XSD equivalent schema if you wanted to, but on the understanding that this would not be the "official" schema for AtomPub. However, I'm sure that others would appreciate your efforts if you did this. Alternatively, you could just use RNG to model yr own types and forego using XSD but then you won't get Visual Studio support

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to re-use the definitions (like `edited`) available in other schema's. For this, you need to import those other schema's into your own schema using [xsd:import](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_import.asp). So you have to find those schemas.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be some schema files available at https://tools.oasis-open.org/version-control/browse/wsvn/cmis/trunk/SchemaProject/schema/ - how "official" they are, I can't tell...